# How do I get the client's IP address in Node.js when using the HTTP2 module?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, http2

I want to get user client's IP address. This is my code:

```
const server = http2.createSecureServer({

  key: fs.readFileSync('localhost.key'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('localhost.crt')

});

server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  console.log('Path:' + headers[':path']);
  console.log('User Agent:' + headers['user-agent']);
  console.log('Cookie:' +  headers.cookie);

  stream.respond({
    'content-type': 'text/html',
    ':status': 200
  });

  stream.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');

});
```

I have already read the node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html). There I found this example:

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const server = http2.createServer((req, res) => {
  const ip = req.socket.remoteAddress;
  const port = req.socket.remotePort;
  res.end(`Your IP address is ${ip} and your source port is ${port}.`);
}).listen(3000);
```

But they don't use the stream object. So my question is, how can I get the client's IP address with my code at the very top of this post?

Comment: did you check the `headers['X-Forwareded-For']`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But get an "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

You can try `const ip = stream.session.socket.remoteAddress`

It's not easy to find in documentation, but it works for me ;)

[http2session_and_sockets in docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http2.html#http2_http2session_and_sockets) find the "http2session.socket" chapter